# program is ignoring asynchronous mode

Tags: javascript, node.js

please could someone help me?

for some reason the program is ignoring asynchronous mode.

code result =
[]
test

what am I doing wrong?

```
var linha = [];

async function func(){

  const { PdfReader } = require('pdfreader');

  const reader = new PdfReader();

  await reader.parseBuffer(req.file.buffer,  (err, item)  => {
      if (err)
        console.error(err);

      else if (!item)
        console.log('Done.');

      else if (item.text) {
        linha.push(item.text);
        console.log('test');
      }
  });
}

await func();
console.log(linha);
```

Comment: How do you know it's ignoring async? What output do you get?

Comment: You cannot use await outside of async function. Second last line

Comment: Fundamental problem here.  `await` ONLY does anything useful when you `await` a promise.   Since `reader.parseBuffer()` is not returning a promise, your function is not hooked into the completion of that operation at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `reader.parseBuffer` does not return a promise. It fires the callback that you've provided.
Essentially, the syntax is a bit off. You can wrap `reader.parseBuffer` to "promisify" the method like this:

```js
var linha = [];

const { PdfReader } = require('pdfreader');
const reader = new PdfReader();
const promiseParseBuffer = buffer => new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    reader.parseBuffer(buffer,  (err, item)  => {
        if (err) return reject(err);
        
        resolve(item);
    });
});

async function func(){

    try {
        const item = await promiseParseBuffer(req.file.buffer);

        console.log(item);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}

await func();
console.log(linha);
```